# Exporting and Importing WordPress Media Libraries and Galleries

Tags: import, export

I'm trying to migrate a series of blogs from one place to another, both running 3.0.1, and I am unable to get media libraries and galleries to come across in the export/import process.

Any ideas on how to do this? The gallery shortcode comes across in the post content, but it doesn't display anything because the actual gallery does not come across.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I noticed that the post_type 'attachment' has the 'can_export' setting set to false. This is causing my media not to export. Does anyone know why it's like that?

Comment: Your answer is here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95683/31384
Wish you luck

Answer (score 2):

Is the migration down to the fact you're moving servers and/or domains? Or that your merging into another blog?

If the former, you might be better off with a database dump (search and replace old domain with new one if that's changing too), then import into the new database (along with copying over the filesystem).

If it's the latter, well, it's not going to be as easy. Let me know if it is, and we'll see what we can do :)

Comment: I'm wanting to migrate 40 blogs into one blog (on a different domain in WP 3.0.1 Multisite), and I will distinguish posts that used to be on separate blogs by using custom taxonomies. We're having all kinds of problems, but blog post URLs and media/galleries are the highest priority items right now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something slightly similar, but with just two blogs into a single new blog.

I used the WordPress Export file to import all the data into the new blog. That went fairly smoothly. Naturally the images and stuff are all messed up...

Both my blogs happened to have the WP uploads folder organized by date. I grabbed both folders and merged them into one. I fortunately didn't run into any duplicated file names.

The URLs were still messed up within the post content. I used the Search Regex to rewrite the urls to the new domain and server path. It was tedious, but I got it done after a few hours.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: That is very helpful. I will test out this process and see if it will work for me. Thanks.

Comment: oh i just noticed you said you want to turn these into a multi-site WP install. My merging was two wordpress blogs into one wordpress blog. Not two installs into a single install. So just a heads up that my process may not exactly work. But the search regex might still come in handy for you. Just be careful not to mess up (have a backup). I liked that plugin because it makes it quite easy to search and preview the result before actually hitting save changes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out through wp-hackers: http://groups.google.com/group/wp-hackers/browse_thread/thread/cbed2605260efe95

Answer (score -2):

url's can be quickly changed from old site to a new site with 'velvet blues update urls'

Comment: Please elaborate a bit which solution you are talking about, where is can be found, and how it fits the question. Thank you. :)