# Media Content disapeared after upgrade WP core to 3.5.1

Tags: media-library, upgrade

my Media -->Library content disappeared from the dashboard, but I still can see it inside my actual site folder.

Could anyone instruct me how to fix it?

Thank You

Comment: 1. what steps did you take to upgrade (automattic ?) 2. check your media settings for the upload media folder location.

Comment: Hi, Krebo99, I do not see media 's folder location in setting-->media. Do you know how can I find it or modify it? Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, My bad , this setting field was REMOVED in 3.5 , and I never even noticed it´s removal...anyhow when you say it disappeared from dashboard, what exactly do you mean ? can you see the contents when you do upload media for example ? do you see any error messages ?

Comment: hi Krembo, thanks for replying, I am able to upload new stuff. no error msg at all, just all the image I had in the library are all gone from media library but they actualy still sit inside the site folder in FTP view.

Comment: you mean when you go to the media -> Library -> all , you see nothing ? and you can still attach new images , but then again, not see them ?

Comment: ..and , it might look irrelevant, but when you try to make a new post , do you see "Publish" or "submit for review" ?

Comment: Yes, you can publish new post and its button I see.

Comment: but I can see whatever comes new.....wait, will it be causing because I deleted one of the main user who made major posts? so library gone because of it? I restore the posts though....

Comment: restored, means, I literarily, restored from the trash...

Comment: Even i am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> **premise** :
>
> I am not so sure as to the exact reason of your problem, but after the
> comments, and considering a normal "user" level of coding expertise, I
> post this answer describing not the ultimate solution, but the steps
> that I myself would have considered when facing a similar problem.
> There might be better approaches and I would love to hear them, but
> like I said, I am posting this as an option to a normal user without
> coding or debugging capabilities.

Strangely enough , yesterday , while commenting to you , a similar thing happened to me on localhost .
After a short investigation, I found out that one of my DB tables (wp_posts) was damaged (first time in 6 years of WP´ing ) .

[image]
[image]

The symptoms were :

- All attachments gone (but still on server).
- Can not publish new posts ( only submit to preview )
- Can not attache new images

AS the symptoms might differ from yours , and so does the recovery , It still `leads me to think that you have some damaged DB table` ..

So, in order to fix this , you can do one of three things :

1 - **Reinstall your website completely including DB**

That depends on how much content you have on the website and on how much time you want to invest in total recovery.

you will essentially need to Copy and paste , upload all images , create new categories  and posts . No import is suggested since we are talking about DAMAGED tables where the information relations themselves are damaged .

2 - **Trying to RESTORE the damaged table** .

GO into your PhpMyadmin, and goto YourDB-->structure
then flag your tables (maybe one by one ) and choose `"restore"`

[image]

3 - **Try to handle the visible symptom** of lost attachments only while ignoring other possible yet-to-be-discovered problems :

While it would be the less recommended for me , it might be the first try for someone with a lot of content and little time .

In that case, I believe your easiest option would be to try to reload all the images . But there is a catch.
If you will upload them AGAIN to the same uploads folder wordpress will try to avoid conflict naming and will rename them with sequential numbers ( eg. `image.jpg` will be uploaded like `image1.jpg` etc ...) which will cause them not to be recognized as the original inserted images ..

So you need to BACKUP you uploads folder to another location, and then DELETE all the images from the wp-content/uploads folder .
At this point , you need to UPLOAD them again from the backup folder , and attach. (thus maintaining the same names )

You could :

- Do it manually on each post (but if you choose this option, it is
  already better to choose recovery option NO.1. )
- Use some plugins like [add-from-server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) and then another one like
  [unattach-and-re-attach](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/unattach-and-re-attach-attachments/) to resolve the problem.
- depending on how automated your site is , and how it is coded , you
  have a third option of attaching all the images only to ONE post in
  order to "uplaod" them and assign GUID , and then they will be recognizable again as
  inserted images , but this option is reserved to someone who knows
  the code well and can handle automattic assignment of post thumbnails
  and featured images etc ..

Note that in order to maintain the same names , you will have to upload only the ORIGINAL sizes and not the custom sizes (meaning `image.jpg` and not `image-800x600.jpg` )

Making a long story short , There is no easy solution as far as I can see for such a problem , but to prevent it in the future , `regularly backup of your DB` is always a good advice.

**WILD GUESS EDIT** Also , in the comments you said that you have deleted a user and then "restored" posts from the DB . This can be also the root of the problem, although hard to confirm.

In this case what you will need to do is something like this :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author=NEW_AUTHOR_ID WHERE post_author=OLD_AUTHOR_ID;
```

But next time, when you delete a user, make sure that you assign all the posts to another user before deleting it .

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer I am going to check it out soon! Will post reply!

Answer (score 0):

OK so you dropped the `wp_posts` table data and then restored the posts from trash. It must work  if Wordpress did not stored the media library entries in `wp_posts` table. The problem is all the entries had removed, there is no record pointing to the uploaded image so Wordpress does not recognize it!

You can see it yourself, open phpMyAdmin or any other MySQLClient and browse the `wp_posts` table, then observe post_type column, there must be some record with type `'attachment'`, and yes, these are those media you uploaded recently. Older entries with type `'attachment'` are not exist anymore, as you deleted them. If you have a back up or something you probably can restore those only attachment data by selecting and exporting them. Maybe this can help you :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95683/31384

Comment: Op has said that he can see the attachments on the media library , so they are presumably not deleted , just the post they were attached to ..