# Import existing image as a single post

Tags: images, uploads

I want to add a bunch of existing images on the server but I want each of them added as a separate post instead of all images into one post. How can I do this?

Comment: images in the media library are themselves posts of the type attachment. do you want to just import the images into the media library, or also create an additional post for each and attach the images to those posts? note that there's no simple way to just use the images where they are on the server, they have to be copied to the uploads directory and added as attachments, this can be automated though.

Comment: Yes I want the images imported to media library and create additional posts for each and attach the image to those posts. How can I automate this?

Comment: the process is a bit involved, a good starting point may be to have a look at the code in the [add from server plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/). you would also have to insert a post via [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) before creating each attachment, so you have a post ID to attach the image to.

Comment: I'm not really a programmer so are there any easier methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67840/where-does-the-media-library-live-in-the-database/67841#67841):

The Media Library lives in both wp_posts and wp_postmeta.

- wp_postmeta contains the image URL
- wp_posts contains an entry for each image insertion into a post, along with the post ID.

Exporting and importing these 2 tables as SQL did not work for me - I received 'duplicate entry for key 7'...

Exporting and importing these 2 tables as CSV did work, using "CSV using load data".

Before importing, I emptied the 2 tables in the recipient database.