# Where is image gallery information saved?

Tags: gallery

Where does Wordpress 4 saves image gallery information? It must be in a file because I have not find anything in the database.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67840/where-does-the-media-library-live-in-the-database

Answer (score 2):

WordPress doesn't necessarily save a ton of gallery information in the database. Each time you upload an image ( or any media I believe ) it gets assigned to a built-in post type called simply "attachment" which gives it a unique ID. Whenever you go through the Media Library Popup and create a gallery, WordPress uses some javascript to generate a shortcode which gets added to the TinyMCE / current page content. The shortcode looks like this:

```
[gallery link="file" columns="5" ids="1,2,3"]
```

You can read up on the [Gallery Shortcode in The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) but the gist of it is that it passes the shortcode a list of Attachment IDs. WordPress then processes this shortcode using the IDs to pull the images from the database and display them in a specific way. You can see the full [Gallery Shortcode Function in Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/).

There's a few filters you could use to modify the gallery on the fly but I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do so here's a list I pulled from the Code Reference linked above:

[`post_gallery`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_gallery) - Allows plugins and themes to override the default gallery template, ie. what the gallery shortcode returns.

[`use_default_gallery_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/use_default_gallery_style/) - Filter whether to print default gallery styles.

[`gallery_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/) - Filter the default gallery shortcode CSS styles.

Comment: I have installed Polylang to make my site multilingual. But I have noticed that when translating pages, if I copy from one language post something like [gallery link="file" columns="5" ids="1,2,3"] to another language post, the image gallery is empty. Thus, I am trying to figure out what to do to make an image gallery in one post be visible in its translated version

Comment: This is another question. Next time please add the full info to the question.